# \lstinputlisting interprets special characters from included file

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a report with multiple programming languages. At the moment I'm trying to include a Makefile.

When I do:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=make]{./Kodeeksempler/makefile}
```

I get the following error compiling with texlive in texmaker:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.22 ]{./Kodeeksempler/makefile}
```

Line 22 of the makefile in question contains the following:

```
BUILD_DIR=build/host
```

.. So I know the error message is wrong, as that should be able to display fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The same occurs when I try to do lstlisting around the makefile regularly like so:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
clean:
     $(RM) ./build
     $(RM) ./bin
     @echo "Static libraries persist in ./lib"

     ${BUILD_DIR}/%.d: %.cpp
     $(CXX) -MT ${BUILD_DIR}/$(@:.d=.o) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $^ > $@

-include $(DEPS)
\end{lstlisting}
```

**EDIT**:

I seem to have narrowed down that the error occurs around the line:

```
-include $(DEPS)
```

When I remove it, lstlisting includes it just fine.

**EDIT2**:
This is the lstset I use in my preamble:

```
 \lstset{language=make,                 % Sprog
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,       % Opsaetning af teksten
     keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,        % Noegleord at fremhaeve
          end,break,return,case,
          switch,function},
     keywordstyle=\color{blue},             % Opsaetning af noegleord
     commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},     % Opsaetning af kommentarer
     stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},      % Opsaetning af strenge
     showstringspaces=false,                    % Mellemrum i strenge enten vist eller blanke
     numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,       % Linjenumre
     extendedchars=true,                    % Tillader specielle karakterer
    columns=flexible,                       % Kolonnejustering
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     % Bryd lange linjer
}
```

I have noticed that even when I omit the last part of the makefile, it seems to work.

**EDIT3**:

So I found the issue! Appearently the @ key was used as an escape character for an old lstset for C code, and it came back in as a result of a merge conflict. Line 199 in the preamble contained the following:

```
 \lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}
```

I removed it, and now it works. Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: Define special characters? Is the file uf8? As always on this site we prefer full examples we can copy and (attempt to) compile without having to add anything

Comment: I have updated my question now. I finally seem to have narrowed down where the issue is.

Comment: But please update it to a complete example, there is no preamble, no documentclass. If you add up complete example, the ever present mwe, then it is a lot easier to help you

Comment: you must have a `\lstset` in your document or the document class. And I suppose that you have the option `mathescape` set.

Comment: @Herbert: I don't think that's the problem: if you make a minimal document with just `\usepackage{listings}` in the preamble and the Makefile from the question, it compiles fine.